# Angular 2 Array of Objects get one value of each (5+5=10)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i got array of Objects which is something like this ;

```
array [
0 { price: 15 }
1 { price:18 }
]
```

I want to get all prices and then write a summary of it  = 15+18 = **33**

```
  export class CartItems {
    price: number;
    }
 cartItems: CartItems[];
this.cartItems = this.cart.products; // I get array from my service
```

HTML (I can get each ones price) :

```
<div *ngFor="let cart of cartItems; let i = index">
<p>{{cart.price}}
</div>
<div> Here I want my summ of all prices to be </div>
```

**How to get summ of all prices ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ts:

```
this.sum = this.cartItems.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b.price, 0);
```

html :

```
<div *ngFor="let cart of cartItems; let i = index">
<p>{{cart.price}}
</div>
<div>{{sum}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) iteration method and getting the sum of two elements, passed to callback. In your case it should be something like this:

```js
const array = [
  {
    price: 15
  },
  {
    price: 18
  }
];
const sum = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b.price, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

In provided example you have only `number` types, but for insurance you can add `+` before items to transform them to numbers:

```
const sum = array.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b.price, 0);
```